# machine learning from negative tagging

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, text-mining

I apply machine learning on free text in order to classify it to one of 120 classes. The algorithm learns from set of X Strings that are pre-classified.

- "this is text 1" (class 1)
- "this is text 2" (class 2)
- ...

Given new text the algorithm returns match rank for each of the possible classes.

In order to make the model better I must feed it with more and more data of positive classified text.

I wonder if there are models that can also learn from negatively classified texts. Meaning "text X" is definitely not (class 3,4,5) - but without knowing what is the positive class.

For example: say that I only take the top 5 ranked classes, and all 5 are wrong, I want to be able to give negative feedback so that the next time I ask for the top 5 on the same text, the machine will return something else.